# c++のwhile文が無限ループしてしまう

Tags: c++

```
n=1;
while(n<=5)
cout<< n << '';
n++;
```

上記コードですが、
`1 2 3 4 5`と表示されると思いきや、なぜか`1 1 1 1 1 1 ・・・`と表示されてしまいます。
理由をご教示頂けますと幸いです。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ループする範囲を中括弧で囲んでください。

元々のコードは以下の形をしています。

```
while (n <= 5)
cout << n << ' ';
n++;
```

このコードでは、while 文によってループするのは `cout << n << ' ';` の行のみです。ループする範囲を中括弧で指定しない場合、while 文のすぐ次の部分 **のみ** がループすることになります。分かりやすくインデントを付けて書くと、以下のようなネスト構造になっています。

```
while (n <= 5)
    cout << n << ' ';  /* この行のみが while ループの範囲内 */
n++;                   /* この行は while ループの外 */
```

次のように中括弧で囲むように書くと、`cout << n << ' ';` と `n++;` の2行が共にループするようになります。構造の分かりやすさのためにインデントも付けています。

```
while (n <= 5) {
    cout << n << ' ';
    n++;
}
```